# React router Link not working when adding onClick handler to button inside the Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a form where, when the user presses the submit button, I wish to do some calculations with the input data and then take the user to a new page.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="app">
          <Navbar />
          <main className="content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Calculator />} />
              <Route path="/results" element={<Return />} />
            </Routes>
          </main>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Calculator.js**

```
function Calculator() {
  return (
    <>
        // Form inputs etc.

        <Link to="/results">       
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click</button>
        </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

For a reason unbeknown to me, the Link works when the onClick event handler is not attached to the button but when I add the onClick event handler, the Link no longer works. With the onClick event handler added to the button, the `handleSubmit` function runs but the Link does not go to the `/results` page

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, can you please upload the code of the `handleSubmit` event listener? If you prevented the default behavior of the click event, it might be the issue with the link

Comment: ahh yes thats it @ShakyaPeiris. I was calling ```e.preventDefault()``` in the ```handleSubmit``` function. Without calling preventDefault() it runs the handleSubmit function and takes the user to the link. It appears as though the default form submitting behaviour is being prevented without running ```e.preventDefulat()````. Is this correct? and is this because of the <Link>?

Comment: Yes, it's my guess as well that you've either preventing the the default link action from occurring or your are not preventing the default form action from occurring.

Comment: @DanielEvans to prevent default form behavior you have to add a **submit** event listener to the form and prevent the default behavior of that listener. Also, you have to change the type of the button to `submit`.  A regular button click won't trigger the submit event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnClick in button is blocking the event to the parent in dom
You can use `useNavigate` instead of Link to handle this (For old versions of react-router-dom it is `useHistory`)

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
function Calculator() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const handleSubmit = () => {
      //your code
      
      navigate("/results")
  }
  return (
    <>
        // Form inputs etc.

             
         <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click</button>
        
    </>
  );
}
```